# Swift javascript/ios bridge breaks swipe gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, swift

I have a swipe gesture recognizer to bring a toolbar off and on the screen. It was working beautifully until I added a JavaScript to iOS bridge using WKUserContentController(). The bridge works, successfully printing the JavaScript message, but swiping no longer works. But if I comment out `Webview = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: configuration)` and `view.addSubview(Webview)` the bridge is obviously broken, but the gesture recognizer works. I just can't get them both working at the same time. Where have I gone wrong?

Edit: Maybe this is relevant: with the code as below, the activity indicator does not appear when the WebView is loading. Also, if I comment out the lines that start the toolbar hidden (starting point swiped off the page), the toolbar should appear, but it doesn't:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate,
                           WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    @IBOutlet var Webview: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet var ActInd: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet var Toolbar: UIToolbar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let controller = WKUserContentController()
        controller.add(self, name: "SwiftNative")
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.userContentController = controller

        // commenting out these two lines disables the bridge but activates swiping again
        Webview = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: configuration)
        view.addSubview(Webview)

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.bazleysawesomesite.com")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        Webview.load(request)

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleSwipes(_:)))
        let leftSwipe  = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleSwipes(_:)))

        rightSwipe.direction = .right
        leftSwipe.direction  = .left

        view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }

    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        print("Message from beyond: \(message.body)")
    }

    // Make the status bar text light
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
    }

    // Start the toolbar "hidden"
    // commenting out these lines should make the toolbar appear, but it doesn't
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        Toolbar.center.x = Toolbar.center.x - self.view.frame.width
    }

    // Activity Indicator stuff
    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ : WKWebView) {
        ActInd.startAnimating()
    }
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ : WKWebView) {
        ActInd.stopAnimating()
        if self.Toolbar.center.x > 0 {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.Toolbar.center.x = self.Toolbar.center.x - self.view.frame.width
            }) 
        }
    }

    // handle swipes
    func handleSwipes(_ sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if (sender.direction == .right) {
            if self.Toolbar.center.x < 0 {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.Toolbar.center.x = self.Toolbar.center.x + self.view.frame.width
                }) 
            }
        }
        if (sender.direction == .left) {
            if self.Toolbar.center.x > 0 {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.Toolbar.center.x = self.Toolbar.center.x - self.view.frame.width
                }) 
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: check the thread of where the webkit handlers are called?

Comment: also, why not add the recognized to just the Toolbar. Isn't that what you want to swipe?

Comment: The toolbar will spend most of its life off the screen, and it comes in on top of current content. It is therefore important that the swipe gesture recognizer is on the whole screen.

Comment: @Bazley. I am having few ideas to solve your issue. Please let know did you get debug point in this method func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}

Comment: If I add that method (it insisted on shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith rather than shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer) then it still runs the same way, no debug point appeared.

Comment: wkwebview already has swipe Gesture i.e. allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures. [refer this]https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview